# labels next to radio group with same name not work on second form

Tags: html, css

I have the following  multiple radio group  with same name

the label next to radio buttons work good with first form1
but in the second from2 the labels works on the radio buttons on the first form1
as this link https://jsfiddle.net/2dp63kw0/

```
<style>
.custom-radio label {
    color:#FFF;
    border-radius:20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size:10pt;
  font-family:arial;
  background-color: #6D778A;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.custom-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

.custom-radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #114ABB;
}

</style>

<form id="form1">
<div style="padding:20px;display:inline" class="custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction0" value="left" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction0">left</label>
    <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction1"  value="top" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction1">right</label>
</div>
</form>
    <hr>
<form id="form2">   

<div style="padding:20px;display:inline" class="custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction0"  value="left" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction0">left</label>
    <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction1"  value="top" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction1">right</label>
</div>
</form>
```

every labels next to radio buttons work on form which it belongs to

Comment: you are repeating ids change second form input ids and label for attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the "name" and "for" attributes in the second form with id=form2.

Also, use class instead of id if you want to apply same properties, as id is unique and used for a single element.

Try this:

```css
.custom-radio label {
    color:#FFF;
    border-radius:20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size:10pt;
  font-family:arial;
  background-color: #6D778A;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.custom-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

.custom-radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #114ABB;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
<div style="padding:20px;display:inline" class="custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction0" value="left" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction0">left</label>
    <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction1"  value="top" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction1">right</label>
</div>
</form>
    <hr>
<form id="form2">   

<div style="padding:20px;display:inline" class="custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="directionb" id="direction2"  value="left" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction2">left</label>
    <input type="radio" name="directionb" id="direction3"  value="top" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction3">right</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` values you have used for the `input` tags are not unique so the first element with the `id` value is used.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.

Change the `id` values for the `input` tags in your second form.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.custom-radio label {
    color:#FFF;
    border-radius:20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size:10pt;
  font-family:arial;
  background-color: #6D778A;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.custom-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

.custom-radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #114ABB;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
<div style="padding:20px;display:inline" class="custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction0" value="left" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction0">left</label>
    <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction1"  value="top" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction1">right</label>
</div>
</form>
    <hr>
<form id="form2">   

<div style="padding:20px;display:inline" class="custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction3"  value="left" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction3">left</label>
    <input type="radio" name="direction" id="direction4"  value="top" />
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="direction4">right</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide details in your answer, not only code.